# How to connect transformer with a full-bridge rectifier in LTspice?

Tags: transformer, ltspice, simulation

I'm struggling with connecting the transformer to my circuit.

[image]

How am I supposed to connect it there? Unfortunately, I am having a floating nodes error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this connection avoid the errors you mentioned?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked, thank you so much